# NgBootstrap Error after using in other component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

> ERROR Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'className:
>   undefined'. Current value: 'className: modal-backdrop fade show'. It
>   seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children
>   have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection
>   hook ?"

In Component:

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

open() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalChoiceComponent);
}

ngOnInit() {this.open();}
```

In my Modal:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-choice',
    template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ModalChoiceComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In my AppModule:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER} from '@angular/core';
[...]
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {NgbModalModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModalChoiceComponent } from './modal-choice/modal-choice.component';


export function init_app(config: ConfigService) {
    return () => config.initialize();
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        [...]
        MainComponent,
        ModalChoiceComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        [...]
        NgbModalModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [
        ModalChoiceComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I really dont know whats the issue. I followed the exactly example from the "ngBootstrap" documentation.

Comment: You know this error only comes in development mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular form directives have bindings that update synchronously based on focus change 
 The modal brings focus to the window

**
To fix this issue use event.preventDefault() and blur() method

Pass the object to open method

```
<input type="text" [readonly]="true" placeholder="Please select a user" (focus)="open($event)" formControlName="username" class="form-control"/>

open(event) {
        event.srcElement.blur();
        event.preventDefault();
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalChoiceComponent);
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1oedu4